# Yahoo New Finance API

Tags: finance, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

Someone at work mentioned that there is a new API for Yahoo finance, I've been doing a lot of research but i can't seem to find any documentation on it. Most of my search results come back with complaining about the old one being down.

Does any one know anything about this or might have a link?

Any links would be useful and sorry if this is a bad question

Thanks,
Kristian

Answer (score 2):

I saw a new Yahoo Finance API from the following link, it may be  unofficial one. As described in the document, it provides 4 APIs :
_ Get data for drawing chart
_ Get movers
_ Get quotes
_ And a API to get summary data in general

You will need to register an account to consume the free quota plan : https://market.mashape.com/apidojo/yahoo-finance

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say they had a new API. I would say they unplugged their APIs for both current quotes and historical quotes. They still offer CSV files for their portfolio and historical quotes, but they require credentials ("&userid", or "&crumb" and cookie). For most purposes, their web pages are now loaded from data in JSON files, including historical quotes, option quotes, and their portfolio function.